# SQL GROUP BY taking too long for multiple columns

Tags: sql, group-by

It takes a reasonable amount of time to run the following query and get the results:

```
SELECT {col1} COUNT(col3) FROM {table1} GROUP BY {col1} LIMIT 100
```

But when I run for multiple columns (as below), it takes for ever!

```
SELECT {col1}, {col2} COUNT(col3) FROM {table1} GROUP BY {col1}, {col2} LIMIT 100
```

I looked for ways to make it more efficiently, but I did not find anything that works for me. I am posting to get new thoughts/directions. Thanks!

- {table1} is relatively huge (~12B rows)

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: you may get select response time improvements with indexing on col1 and col2. Not sure on database you are using.